# How to deserialize json using groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to parse a JSON file using groovy.
Json:

```
{
    "Node1": {
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "OS": "linux",
        "Policy_Group": "abc"
    },
    "Node2": {
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "OS": "linux",
        "Policy_Group": "xyz"
    }
}
```

How can I fetch the values of Environment, OS, Policy_Group using groovy.

I am trying below but its not woring

```
serverJson[serverLabel].each { serverData ->
print serverData.Environment
print serverData."Environment"
}
```

where `serverlabel` is the `Node1`, `Node2` and `serverJson` is the json file

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File("path_to_file\\example.json");
slurperResponse = new JsonSlurper().parse(file);

slurperResponse.each{
    it -> 
      print (it.getValue().get("Environment"));
      print (it.getValue().get("OS"));
}
```

Here 'it' is an implicit variable. Check [documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#implicit-it)

These are the imports you will need;

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
```

Comment: You don't need `import java.io.File;`

Comment: @tim_yates - Removed java.io.File import

Comment: Will it parse through each node?, I mean I need data for Node1 in first iteration and so on.

Comment: Yes. This is a for-each loop in Groovy. This will print;  
NPR // Node1 -> Environment
linux // Node1 -> OS
NPR // Node2 -> Environment
linux // Node2 -> OS

Comment: Is there any way to get Node specific data and not everything. E.g I want to get "Environment" value for Node1

Comment: Yes you can get it as `slurperResponse.Node1.Environment`.  
  
You have to write the json-path to the key (Environment in Node1) you need.